# Laravel 5 file downloads invalid

Tags: php, laravel, download, laravel-5

When using `Response::download` to download files, I noticed that images and other binary files were being transferred incorrectly.

Changing the `Content-Type` header didn't change anything, nor did explicitly disallowing cache or forcing the content's length.

What may be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "transferred incorrectly"? For example, were the transferred files empty? Were images garbled/corrupted? Did the file length change?

Comment: Sorry, yes - for more context, images and other binary files were corrupted due to extra characters being transferred. When I get some time I'll show the hex diffs between the uploaded file (correct) and the downloaded file (corrupt)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The solution to this problem can be found here:

http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-fix-laravel-response-image-download-in-laravel/

The cause of the issue was due to Laravel/Symfony not properly cleaning the output buffer for some reason, so the solution is this:

```
$response = Response::download($path, ...);
ob_end_clean();

return $response;
```

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem, had an issue downloading a generated zip file.

Comment: Just a note to add a link to a laravel issue referencing this problem, together with Taylor's response... https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2892