# Laravel file corrupted when dowloaded in private file system

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to create private file system for my website. Each user should be able to see its own file. To do so, I created a class `GetFile` as follow

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\Tasks;


class GetFile
{
    private static $localFilePath = "attached_files";

    public static function getFile($filename)
    {
        return response()->download(storage_path(self::$localFilePath ."/".$filename, null, [], null));
    }
}
```

Then I created a `GetFileController` controller as follow

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Tasks\GetFile;

class GetFileController extends Controller
{
    public function get_file($file_name)
    {
        return GetFile::getFile($file_name);
    }
}
```

and then a route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth'], 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function () {
    Route::get('get_file/{file_name}', 'GetFileController@get_file')->name('file.get_file');
});
```

Now the

```
route('file.get_file', $filename)
```

is a link to the `$filename`. When someone tries to see a file, I can control the access with some logic in `get_file` function of controller.

The problem is when I download a file (an image) by this method, The Windows OS says the file is corrupted or too long and it can't open the file. I am really confused, I already created private file system this way and every thing was right, but this time some thing went wring. I check the files on the server, they have no problem, so I guess something should be wrong in download function.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be due to the output buffer not being cleared.

```
ob_end_clean();
```

The above should clear the buffer so use it before you download things.

There is more information in the answer here:
[Laravel 5 file downloads invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906595/laravel-5-file-downloads-invalid)

Answer (score 1):

May be whitespace ruining the header() function.

Try this :

```
public static function getFile($filename)
{
   ob_end_clean();
   $headers = array(
     'Content-Type: image/png',
   );
   return response()->download(storage_path(self::$localFilePath ."/".$filename, $headers));
}
```

Comment: Files are not always image. it may be a zip file. Thank you for your response