# Wrong Mimetype or Extension when creating a download file API

Tags: php, laravel, rest, download

I am working on a laravel project and make it to serve as a RESTful API.

So I have a feature where user can download files that I store from azure blob storage, the file is in an excel file and sometimes CSV, I have successfully create the download feature, but when I try to open the file it says something like this

[image: The Error message on excel]

I use this method to get the MIME types of the file

```
$mimeType = finfo_buffer(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), $file);
```

And it give me this mime type 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' which then I put in the response headers like down below

```
$headers = [
                'Content-Type' => $mimeType,
                'Content-Description' => 'File Transfer',
                'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename=" . $fileName,
                'filename' => $fileName
            ];
```

But then the problem happens and I try to open the properties of the CORRECT file, it says like this

> 'Content-type' : 'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12'

So is there any way to make my response giving the same file that produce no error of extension to the downloaded file?

Comment: Try to get the Mime Type using getMimeType() methode. This works for me to check the file type before upload and give the correct mime type for many types i have checked.

Comment: Assuming you mean desktop Excel (the screenshot suggests so), that program loads files from your local disk, it will not download them for the internet, so MIME types are irrelevant. I suspect the file actually contains some error message returned by server, it's encoded, or it was never a valid spreadsheet in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that the cause of the issue was due to Laravel/Symfony not properly cleaning the output buffer for some reason, you can find the solution down here:

http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-fix-laravel-response-image-download-in-laravel/

[Laravel 5 file downloads invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906595/laravel-5-file-downloads-invalid)

In my case, here is how I implemented it:

```
$response = Response::download($path, ...);
ob_end_clean();

return $response;
```